# Unable to boot from ISO image

Tags: boot, live-cd, bios

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on VMplayer. Now I want to increase the primary partition size. In the Virtual machine setting, I gave ISO image(13.04) path to CD Drive. After booting the VM, I tried to get into BIOS menu by pressing F2 (tried all keys!!) but was not successful.

Also please let me know how can I increase the primary partition size.

Please give me some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are instructions for increasing the size of the virtual hard disk, which I assume you are trying to do.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004047

Then just reboot into ubuntu and you should have a bigger partition